# Is it possible to put the cursor on the first item on auto-completion?

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-deoplete

I added and use [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) to get a list of completion while typing. However, typing in a word shows the completion list with the cursor being nowhere on the list.

On some IDEs like Xcode, when you type in a word, the completion pops up with the cursor already on the first item. So it is possble to just push <kbd>return</kbd> to choose the completion, instead of pushing <kbd>down</kbd> and <kbd>return</kbd>.

This is more convenient yet all the GIFs on the deocomplete Github page don't put the cursor on the first item. Is it possible to archive this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the `noinsert` flag in `completeopt` in combination with `menu`, the first item will be selected (but not inserted into the buffer).

```
 set completeopt=menu,noinsert
```